# ¿Qué esta mal en el código de Stata?

Tags: stata

Estoy tratando de corregir el comando, debido a que al correrlo en Stata no funciona, como referencia es del libro  Time Series Econometrics. Learning through en el apartado "Problems with OLS in Models with LDVs", pp. 19.

```
drop _all
set seed 123
postfile buffer beta1 using filename,replace
forvalues i = 1/1000 /*the number of replications*/ {
  qui drop _all
qui set ob 20 /*the number of observations*/
qui gen time = _n
qui tsset time
qui gen double error = rnormal
*generate y
qui gen double y =
qui replace y = error in 1
qui replace y= 0.50*l1 .y +error in 2/l
qui reg y l1.y /*estimates the regression*/
post buffer (_b^[l.y]) /*saves the estimate*/
}
Postclose buffer /*closes the file of the estimates*/ 
*Kernel density grap
Use filename.dta , clear
Kdensity beta1
```